# Por que mi boton de html no funciona?

Tags: html

No entiendo porque mi boton no funciona en mi html

```
<div class="card-button">
          <button class="btn-blue" href="mailto:#######" target="_blank">Contacto</button>
          <button class="btn-orange" href="https://allmylinks.com/#######" target="_blank">Seguir</button>
        </div>
```

Comment: Un botón no tiene atributo href, este atributo funciona con ```<a>```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según lo que he podido entender, aquí te va una solución:

## Breve Explicación

El error está en que los botones no tienen la propiedad *href*. Deberías usar un onclick y ejecutar un código javascript que cambie la ubicación.

## Código

```html
<div class="card-button">
          <button class="btn-blue" onclick="document.location.href='mailto:#######'" target="_blank">Contacto</button>
          <button class="btn-orange" onclick="document.location.href='https://allmylinks.com/#######'" target="_blank">Seguir</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias, me sirvió

Comment: Un placer, no olvides marcar la respuesta en solución para evitar que otros entren a responder algo ya solucionado.

Comment: Por cierto, no está demás recordar que [se recomienda ya no utilizar los _manejadores de eventos en línea_ (_inline event handlers_)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Events#inline_event_handlers_%E2%80%94_dont_use_these).